# MATCHING AN INTEGER

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataset. I want to create a `dataframe` from the dataset which starts with a particular integers.

**This is a sample:**

```py
box = {'colors': ['Green','Yellow','Green','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red','Green','Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow','Green',
                  'Green','Green','Yellow','Green','Green','Green','Green','Green'],
      'shapes': ['Rectangle','Circle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square',
                 'Square','Rectangle','Circle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle', 'Rectangle','Square','Rectangle',
                 'Square','Circle'],
      'Terminal_ID': [5061739764654, 90908743645343, 50614354347865, 50617343645343, 90908746543363, 50617489752564, 
                      50617443645343, 50614464234764, 9764654, 50614343645343, 50614446543363, 50614389752564, 
                      50614443645343, 64234764,5061439764654, 90908743645343, 50614346543363, 87500089752564, 50617443645343,
                      50614364234764, 8750009764654]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(box, columns = ['Terminal_ID','colors', 'shapes'])
```

**NOTE: ** The objective is to form a dataframe from this dataset whose *Terminal_ID* starts with $506143$ and $506173$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
 df2['Terminal_ID'] = df2['Terminal_ID'].astype('str')
 df2[df2['Terminal_ID'].str.contains("506143| 506173", na=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out these numbers in the data frame coloumn, you could try the following steps:

1. Split each row of the data frame column in a array of strings [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906717/splitting-integer-in-python)];
2. Merge the six first strings of each array [[2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join)];
3. Compare the numbers you are looking for with the array of merged numbers [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)];
4. Select the positions of the rows that begins with the numbers desired [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)].

```
import pandas as pd

box = {'colors': ['Green','Yellow','Green','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red','Green','Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow','Green',
              'Green','Green','Yellow','Green','Green','Green','Green','Green'],
  'shapes': ['Rectangle','Circle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square',
             'Square','Rectangle','Circle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle', 'Rectangle','Square','Rectangle',
             'Square','Circle'],
  'Terminal_ID': [5061739764654, 90908743645343, 50614354347865, 50617343645343, 90908746543363, 50617489752564, 
                  50617443645343, 50614464234764, 9764654, 50614343645343, 50614446543363, 50614389752564, 
                  50614443645343, 64234764,5061439764654, 90908743645343, 50614346543363, 87500089752564, 50617443645343,
                  50614364234764, 8750009764654]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(box, columns = ['Terminal_ID','colors', 'shapes'])

num1 = 506143
num2 = 506173

# 1
def digits(number, base=10):
    assert number >= 0
    if number == 0:
        return [0]
    l = []
    while number > 0:
        l.append(str(number % base))
        number = number // base
    l.reverse()
    return l

# 2
digit = [''.join(digits(x)[0:6]) for x in df2['Terminal_ID']]

# 3
pos = [i for i, j in enumerate(digit) if j in (str(num1), str(num2))]

# 4
df3 = df2.loc[pos, ['colors', 'shapes','Terminal_ID']]
print(df3)
#     colors     shapes     Terminal_ID
# 0    Green  Rectangle   5061739764654
# 2    Green  Rectangle  50614354347865
# 3     Blue     Square  50617343645343
# 9     Blue     Square  50614343645343
# 11  Yellow     Circle  50614389752564
# 14   Green     Square   5061439764654
# 16   Green  Rectangle  50614346543363
# 19   Green     Square  50614364234764
```